# Change 3D coordinate system do 2D for triangulation

Tags: c#, matrix, 3d

I need to triangulate a polygon of n points in 3D space. The problem is that the library I'm using only triangulate in 2D. Since my polygons can be oriented in any plane in 3D space, I need to convert these points to 2D and ater triangulation I must convert them back to the original 3D coordinate system.

I think I'm getting lost on the creation of the transformation matrix, from 3D to 2D.

Here's what I'm doing:

1 - Defining the X axis of the new 2D coordinate system as P2 - P1
2 - Defining a helper axis as P3 - P1
3 - Since X and helper are coplanar I use cross product to find the Z axis
4 - Now that I have X and Z, cross product to get Y axis
5 - Normaliza all axis
6 - Create a transformation matrix with those new axis
7 - Multiply the original points by the transformation matrix

Since all points are now coplanar, their Z coordinate should be ZERO, but this is not what's happening. The Z coordinates should at least be equal, because I know I should put translation in the matrix somehow...

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a little example:

```
        Point4D p1 = new Point4D(1, -0.75, -0.3, 1);
        Point4D p2 = new Point4D(1,  0.75, -0.3, 1);
        Point4D p3 = new Point4D(1,  0.75,  0.3, 1);
        Point4D p4 = new Point4D(1, -0.75,  0.3, 1);

        Vector3D xAxis = new Vector3D(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.Z - p1.Z);
        Vector3D hAxis = new Vector3D(p3.X - p1.X, p3.Y - p1.Y, p3.Z - p1.Z);
        Vector3D zAxis = Vector3D.CrossProduct(xAxis, hAxis);
        Vector3D yAxis = Vector3D.CrossProduct(zAxis, xAxis);

        xAxis.Normalize();
        yAxis.Normalize();
        zAxis.Normalize();

        Matrix3D trans = new Matrix3D(xAxis.X, xAxis.Y, xAxis.Z, 0,
                                      yAxis.X, yAxis.Y, yAxis.Z, 0,
                                      zAxis.X, zAxis.Y, zAxis.Z, 0,
                                      0,       0,       0,       1);

        Point4D n1 = p1 * trans;
        Point4D n2 = p2 * trans;
        Point4D n3 = p3 * trans;
        Point4D n4 = p4 * trans;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the translation to the assumed origin and you didn't invert the transformation matrix. So something like this:

```
        Point4D p1 = new Point4D(1, -0.75, -0.3, 1);
        Point4D p2 = new Point4D(1, 0.75, -0.3, 1);
        Point4D p3 = new Point4D(1, 0.75, 0.3, 1);
        Point4D p4 = new Point4D(1, -0.75, 0.3, 1);

        Vector3D xAxis = new Vector3D(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.Z - p1.Z);
        Vector3D hAxis = new Vector3D(p3.X - p1.X, p3.Y - p1.Y, p3.Z - p1.Z);
        Vector3D zAxis = Vector3D.CrossProduct(xAxis, hAxis);
        Vector3D yAxis = Vector3D.CrossProduct(zAxis, xAxis);

        xAxis.Normalize();
        yAxis.Normalize();
        zAxis.Normalize();

        Matrix3D trans = new Matrix3D(xAxis.X, xAxis.Y, xAxis.Z, 0,
                                      yAxis.X, yAxis.Y, yAxis.Z, 0,
                                      zAxis.X, zAxis.Y, zAxis.Z, 0,
                                      p1.X, p1.Y, p1.Z, 1);    // **** changed this
        trans.Invert();    // **** added this

        Point4D n1 = p1 * trans;
        Point4D n2 = p2 * trans;
        Point4D n3 = p3 * trans;
        Point4D n4 = p4 * trans;
```

For your test points, this gives the following results:

```
n1 { 0,    0, 0, 1}
n2 {1.5,   0, 0, 1}
n3 {1.5, 0.6, 0, 1}
n4 {  0, 0.6, 0, 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a transformation trans that obeys e.g. `(1,0,0,1)*trans=xAxis` for your global coordinate x-axis (1,0,0,1) in homogenous coords. Similarly `(0,1,0,1)*trans=yAxis` and `(0,0,1,1)*trans=zAxis`.

But you want a transform A with `xAxis*A--->(1,0,0,1)` and so on, right? So i think you should invert trans and do `n1=p1*invert(trans)`.

Comment: Wasn't getting why I had to use the inverse matrix, but now I get why I have to invert it... Thank you so much